# Center vertically a div after a displacement from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, animation

I would like to center the `.presentation` div vertically after a displacement from bottom to top of 10%.

My code works when `#home-header` get an height of 100% but when I change it to 75% for example, that's don't works...

How to fix it please ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/4t9vsym3/16/

```
var placement = ($('#home-header').outerHeight()-$('.presentation').outerHeight())/2;

$('.presentation').animate({bottom: placement, opacity: 1}, 1700);

#home-header {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.presentation {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your top/bottom placement on the presentation if the height of home-header is not 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/4t9vsym3/17/

```
#home-header {
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.presentation {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `var placement = (window.innerHeight - $(".presentation").height()) / 2;`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4t9vsym3/18/

Comment: Unfortunately that's don't work when I set an height of 75% for #home-header

Comment: @Xroad _"Unfortunately that's don't work when I set an height of 75% for #home-header "_ Can describe "don't work" ? Is `.presentation` not centered vertically in viewport at http://jsfiddle.net/4t9vsym3/18/ ?

Comment: Exactly, with 75% .presentation is too low